# Job tracker and Task tracker don't sow up when ran the start-all.sh command in ububtu for hadoop

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hadoop2

Job tracker and Task tracker don't sow up when ran the start-all.sh command in ububtu for hadoop

I do get the rest of the processes while i run the "JPS" command in unix.

Not sure why i am not being shown with the job tracker and task tracker.Have been following couple of links and couldn't get my prob sorted.

Steps done :

-Multiple times formatted the namenode
-Multiple time deleted and recreated the tmp folder with appropriate permissions.

What could be the issue ?

Any suggestions would really help me as i am struggling in setting up hadoop on my laptop.I am new to it though.

Comment: Check job tracker and task tracker logs

Comment: FYI logs for the daemons are located in the `logs` folder of where you have extracted hadoop.

Comment: @h4ck3r can u help me with specific log name. As there are many and I opened each to search tracker in file content.but no luck.

Comment: @Ashrith  can u help me with specific log name. As there are many and I opened each to search tracker in file content.but no luck.

Comment: Default execution framework in hadoop version 2.0 and above will be YARN, MR1(Jobtracker,tasktracker) will be available, If needed you can use it.

Comment: @h4ck3r could you pleaes advise in how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting jobtracker and tasktracker separately.

From your hadoop HOME directory run

```
. bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh
```

Then from hadoop BIN directory run

```
hadoop-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR start jobtracker
hadoop-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR start tasktracker
```

Comment: DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute mapred command is deprecated.
Instead use the mapred command for it.

Sorry, the jobtracker command is no longer supported.
You may find similar functionality with the "yarn" shell command.

hadoop@ubuntu:~/Work/hadoop-2.7.1$ hadoop-daemon.sh --config /home/hadoop/Work/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop start tasktracker
starting tasktracker, logging to /home/hadoop/Work/hadoop-2.7.1/logs/hadoop-hadoop-tasktracker-ubuntu.out
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute mapred command is deprecated.
Instead use the mapred command for it.

Comment: could you please help in this?

Comment: Sorry i am using MR1 not sure about yarn startup issues.

Answer (score 0):

You must have been using hadoop 2.x version where jobtracker is replaced with YARN resource manager. Using `jps`(jdk is needed) you can check whether resouce manager is running. If it is running then the default url for it is (host-name):8088. You can check your nodes,jobs also configuration there.If not running then start them with sbin/start-yarn.sh.